# What rectangle does this statement convey?

Tags: analytic-geometry

What rectangle is this talking about?

The rectangle: $$\{(x,y)\mid 0 \leq x \leq 2 , 0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$$

How does this convey a rectangle?

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The one with corners at (0,0), (2,0), (0,1), and (2,1).

Comment: Why not something in between??

Comment: Yes, it's the full area with the corners mentioned, inclusive of the edges.

Comment: Can you explain to me what that statement means in words? Please.

Comment: @arihant In words: "The set of all $(x, y)$ pairs such that $x$ is between $0$ and $2$ (inclusive) *and* $y$ is between $0$ and $1$ (again inclusive)".

Comment: Thanks pjs. I got it now. So there arr infinitely many points (x,y) here.

Answer (score 0):

It's this rectangle:

[image]

Notice that the corners are at $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(2,0)$, and $(2,1)$.  The rectangle is just all of the points $(x,y)$ such that $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le 1$.